# Exercise 2.8.4 in Einsiedler and Ward

Tags: ergodic-theory

$\newcommand{\set}[1]{\\{#1}\\}$ $\newcommand{\ab}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}$ $\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$ $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}$ $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbf C}$

Exercise 2.8.4 in Einsiedler and Ward's Ergodic Theory with a View Towards Number Theory asks the following.

> **Exercise.** Give a different proof of the mean ergodic theorem as follows.
> For a measure preserving system $(X, \mc X, \mu, T)$ and a function $f\in L^2_\mu$, show that the map $n\mapsto \ab{T^nf, f}:\Z\to \C$ is positive definite and apply the Herglotz-Bochner Theorem to translate the problem into one concerned with functions on $S^1$, and there use the fact that $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} z^n$ converges for each $z\in S^1$.

First let me assume that the system is invertible (otherwise I was facing trouble showing the positive-definiteness of the said map).
Applying the Herglotz-Bochner theorem we can find a positive measure $\rho$ on $S^1$ such that $\hat \rho(n) = \ab{T^nf, f}$ for all $n$.
Let $f_N = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}T^nf$.

*I am only able to show the weak$^\ast$ convergence of $(f_N)_{N\geq 1}$ using the approach mentioned in the problem.*

Note that $\ab{f_N, f} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \hat\rho(n)$.
Using dominated convergence theorem we see that the latter converges to $\rho(1)$.
It follows, by similar reasoning, that $\ab{f_N, T^kf}$ converges to $\hat\rho(1)$ for all $k$.
Now define $S = \overline{\text{Span}\{T^nf:\ n\in \Z}\}$.
It follows that $\ab{f_N, g}$ converges whenever $g\in S$.
Also, if $g\in S^\perp$, then $\ab{f_N, g}$ clearly converges to $0$.
Thus for any $g\in L^2_\mu$ we have that $\ab{f_N, g}$ converges.
This shows the weak* convergence of $f_N$.

How do I upgrade to norm convergence?

Comment: Not sure, but Rudin 'Functional analysis' Theorem 12.44 might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that
$$||f_N||_2=\langle f_N, f_N \rangle = \frac{1}{N^2} \sum_{n,m=0}^{N-1} \langle T^nf,T^mf \rangle,$$
then use the fact that $T$ is measure preserving to obtain
$\langle T^nf,T^mf \rangle = \langle T^{n-m}f,f \rangle$ and then use the Bochner-Herglotz theorem. Indeed, by the theorem there is a finite and positive measure $\sigma_f$, so that
$\langle T^{n-m}f,f \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{S}} z^{n-m}\ d \sigma_{f}(z)$. Therefore, $||f_N||_2$ becomes
$$\frac{1}{N^2} \sum_{n,m=0}^{N-1} \int_{\mathbb{S}} z^n \cdot \bar{z}^m\ d \sigma_{f}(z) = \big|\big| \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} z^n \big|\big|_{L^2(\sigma_f)}.$$

In the same manner one sees that

$$\big| \big| f_N-f_M \big| \big|_2 = \big|\big| \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} z^n - \frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} z^m\big|\big|_{L^2(\sigma_f)}.$$

Then you can use the hint and the dominated convergence theorem to conclude that $(f_N)$ is a Cauchy sequence and thus converges.

Comment: I can elaborate further if you like, although it's fairly straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Though I do not see your idea. Can you elaborate. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for adding details. What this (to me) shows is that the $L^2$-norm of $f_N$ converges as $N\to \infty$. I don't see why this shows that $f_N$ itself converges in the $L^2$-sense as $N\to \infty$.

Comment: Oh, yes, you want convergence in norm! You can repeat the same process to show that $(f_N)$ is Cauchy.

Comment: I'll try it. But usually it is very hard to establish that such averages are Cauchy. A useful tool is here is the van der Corput trick.

Comment: $||f_N-f_M||_2 = || \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^N z^n - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{m=0}^M z^m||_{L^2(\sigma_f)}$, but $(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^N z^n)$ converges pointwise everywhere and is bounded.